# Laravel - Override the resetPassword

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I have two tables of users in my database with the name Mahasiswas and Users, and I want to override the resetPassword for Mahasiswas table, because every time I reset the password for the Mahasiswas table, it automatically logged into the Users dashboard.

I put this in my route :

```
Route::post('password/reset', 'MhsAuth\PasswordController@postMyReset');
```

And this is my passwordController :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\MhsAuth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
class PasswordController extends Controller
{

  use ResetsPasswords;
  protected $redirectPath = '/';
  protected $getGuard = 'mahasiswa';

  public function __construct()
  {
     $this->middleware('mahasiswa');
  }

  public function postMyReset(Request $request)
  {
     return $this->resetMe($request);
  }

  public function resetMe(Request $request)
  {
     $this->validate($request, [
         'token' => 'required',
         'email' => 'required|email',
         'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
     ]);

     $credentials = $request->only(
         'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
     );

     $broker = $this->getBroker();

     $response = Password::broker($broker)->reset($credentials, function ($user, $password) {
            $this->resetMyPassword($user, $password);
     });

        switch ($response) {
                case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
                    return $this->getResetSuccessResponse($response);

                default:
                    return $this->getResetFailureResponse($request, $response);
        }
    }

    protected function resetMyPassword($user, $password)
    {
        $user->password = bcrypt($password);
        $user->save();
        //Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($user);
    }

}
```

The problem is after reset the password for Mahasiswas table, it's perform auto login to Users Dashboard, it should be in Mahasiswas Dashboard, but I just want to disable the autologin and my passwordController doesn't work as I wanted. Thanks

Comment: When you run `php artisan route:list` do you have only one route *password/reset* which is your custom one or more?

Comment: @TheFallen there is only one route password/reset , but it leads to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\passwordController, it should MhsAuth not Auth.

Comment: So your route is not overwriting the Laravel password reset route. Would it work for you if you change your route to something different so it won't be the same as *password/reset*?

Comment: @TheFallen It works now after I put the password/reset route inside the Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'],function(){ }) , I found that Route::auth() contains all the password reset route. But now I have another problem, I can only reset password for Users table because when I input the email of Mahasiswas table it says User With That Email Not Found.

Comment: It's probably looking in the other table. Make sure your controller is responding to the route or make another route with different name.